# How does native code looks like in java. Is assembly language is native code?

Tags: java, native

**What is native code in java ?** 

I know that, it is processor specific code that is made for any specific processor and it will not run on another machine . 
 But i am not able to understand how does it looks like ? 
 Does it looks like assembly language or like c language or like c++. Can any one clear it ? 
And is c and c++  or assembly language also converted into native code?

Comment: Java doesn't necessary *ever* become native code. Java compiles to *bytecode*, which may be entirely interpreted by a JVM. The entire point of Java is that it is portable, i.e. the same Java code can run on different types of processors.

Comment: I know all that you have mentioned But after compilation of java code it is interpreted by java interpreter but finally it get converted into native code. So what is that native code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytecode is translated to native code at runtime. It doesn't look like assembler because assembler is source code, for humans. Instead, native code looks like voltage levels of 0V relative to ground and +5V relative to ground, for most computers we encounter these days, or other values depending on the hardware.

Comment: thanks  to answer  . This is the answer that i wanted to know thank you so much MR.Lew Bloch